# c# timer с дополнительными аргументами

Tags: c#

Есть таймер

```
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer testTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
testTimer.Tick += DoThis();
testTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,3);
testTimer.Start();
```

Метод:

```
public void DoThis(int x){ }
```

Как вызывать метод таймером и при этом передавать в него параметр?

Ничего не получается, вызов ломается при добавлении этого `int x`

Comment: Просто вложите в `DoThis()` вызов другого метода, но уже с нужным вам параметром.

Comment: Вообще, код в вопросе тоже нерабочий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
testTimer.Tick += () => DoThis(0);
```

```
int x = 0;
testTimer.Tick += () => DoThis(x++);
```